# Odoo 10 Change form view Many2one res.partner

Tags: odoo, odoo-10, odoo-view

I have a custom odoo app. In my model I have a Many2One form the type res.partner.
If I display the field `<field name="projectmanager" domain="[('partner_type', '=', 'Manager')]"/>` in a form view, I get the name, address, city and country.
How can I hind the address and display only the name?

The model:

```py
class CalamityCalamity(models.Model):
    _name = 'calamity.calamity'
    _inherit = ['mail.thread']
    _description = 'Schadelijsten'
    _order = "projectnr"
    _rec_name = "projectnr"

    projectnr       = fields.Char(string='Projectnummer')
    projectmanager  = fields.Many2one('res.partner', ondelete='set null', string="Projectmanager", index=True,  domain=[('partner_type','=','Manager')])
```

Comment: It is not because of your module, another module is touching the display_name of res.partner

Answer (score 1):

Many2one field always open the default form view but you can change this And define witch form using xml id

```
 <field name="projectmanager"  context="{'form_view_ref': 'module_name.form_id'}"/>
```

Just create a new form that display what you need exactly

Answer (score 0):

did you tried this

```
<field name="projectmanager" options='{"widget": "contact", "fields": ["name"]}'/>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but this do nothing.

Answer (score 0):

try to replace "res.partner" with "partner_id.field_name".

```
projectmanager  = fields.Many2one('partner_id.name', ondelete='set null', string="Projectmanager", index=True,  domain=[('partner_type','=','Manager')])
```

Hope this will help you.